# Comparing and updating the fields in firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to update Username password group name.
I am trying like this, but it is not updating

I want to camapre and then update my fields, but i can't find a way to do that.

Like where email = komaldeep1993@gmail.com
update there;

my code looks like this.
thanks

```
    var newData = {
        Username: this.username.value,
        Password: this.password.value,
        User_Group: this.User_Group.value,
    }

      var email = this.state.edit_details[0];




    firebase.database().ref("/Cred_Details_Of_Users").orderByChild("Email_Address").equalTo(email).update(newData);
```

this is not working , help me updating the specific field by camparting data in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `update()` on a query. You will need to call it on the `DatabaseReference` of each specific child that is matched by that query:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("/Cred_Details_Of_Users").orderByChild("Email_Address").equalTo(email);
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref.update(newData);
})
```